# Spring - designing utility modules

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns

A Spring application design question. I want to write a utility java library and this is going to be a dependency across all my other small applications. All my applications are spring based applications. Is it a good practice to use auto wiring in the utility library module. And this utility library needs few properties to be read from the properties file. How are we going to approach writing my common utility library when the other applications which uses this module would be spring based?

Comment: It is best practice to have a library depend on **as little as possible** - ideally nothing. If you do introduce a dependency, think long and hard about whether it is necessary and what burden it will place on library consumers. Personally, I _hate_ libraries that have Spring embedded - I much prefer good documentation and to configure them in Spring myself. If you decide, after a *huge* amount of thought, that using Spring in your library solves more problems than it creates - then _please_ use Spring autoconf and require users to explicitly enable the library's functionality.

Comment: See [the Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html).

Comment: Your library is going to be Spring-agnostic (it shouldn't rely on Spring dependencies). You'd better write an adapter to tie up the library with a Spring application.

Comment: Oh, and one thing I hate more than libraries with heavyweight frameworks as a dependency, are libraries that read arbitrary properties files. ARGH. Create an `interface MyLibraryConfiguration`, add any config properties you need to the `interface`. You now have a **type safe** and **agnostic** configuration. If the user wants to read from a properties file, that's fine. If the user wants to hardcode properties, that's fine too. If the user wants to ask an orchestrator for the properties - also good.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use autowiring on a utility library if you can help it. Just use dependency inversion to delay the injection of dependencies until the moment you're actually using the library. Then you can declare it as a bean in your client applications and use autowiring if you so choose.

The same goes from properties, just make them parameters on the pertinent methods/constructors and then you can use each client app's properties file to define whatever properties you desire.

Comment: Yes, this. If everyone did this I would be a much happier dev! Create an `interface MyLibraryConfiguration` and receive that in the ctor; if the user wants to implement it as a Spring bean and inject the properties that is up to them.